# Titanium Mobile - Create an iPad Popover in NavBar

Tags: ipad, titanium, appcelerator

I am currently playing around with Titanium Mobile and trying to create and populate a popover when a button in the NavBar (at the top) is clicked.  Currently, the popover is created, but it's not populated with any data.  (I'm trying to populate it with a view from my file "category_list.js").

Here's what I have tried so far: http://pastie.org/2145045

**The problem is:**  The popover shows up, but it's not being populated with any data.

**UPDATE:** More specifically, after looking around, I guess what I am trying to do is create a navigation group within a popover.  Apparently, [this forum post](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/65751/possible-to-have-navigation-group-in-popover#answer-208261) says it's possible.

But I can't seem to figure it out.  If anyone can provide a concrete example of how a navigation group works within the context of a popover using Appcelerator, it would help me out tremendously.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Does the code in the forum post example you posted not work? One major difference is you don't have a `navigationWindow` opened at anytime in your code that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/7182213033/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-ipad-popover-with

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this is what I was looking for to get me started.  Much appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if if has anything to do with `popover.add(categories_list);` being called once at line 18 and once in the click event at line 73. When I've worked with popovers in the past you only need to add to it once. Let me know if this gets you anywhere closer to a solution?

The other problem I see that I'm 99% sure is causing this issue is the popovers don't adjust auto to the child view height and width. Try adding `height: 300, width: 250` when creating the popover.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  You've definitely gotten me closer to the solution.  I added the height and width and removed line 18.  However, the popover displays, but with no data.  Here's my new code: http://pastie.org/2145336

Comment: I've never been able to get a full window in a popover, just child elements(picker, table, scrollviews, ect...)

Comment: Here is my `category_list.js` file if it helps any: http://pastie.org/2145437  What would I need to change in order to get it working?

Comment: include the file rather then creating a new window and add it's elements to the `popover` rather then the window

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for the reply.  I've figured out how to articulate what I am actually trying to do.  I updated my post above.  I'm not sure if this is something you can help out with, or provide an example.  (I learn best with example code).  For whatever reason, I've been racking my brain and cannot figure it out.  Many thanks!